# Android setHomeButtonEnabled() error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-actionbar, android-manifest

I've used the below code in my application.

```
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

I've set

```
android:minSdkVersion="11"
```

in my code. However, every time I edit my AndroidManifest.xml file, it gives an error.

```
Call requires API level 14 (current min is 11):android.app.ActionBar#setHomeButtonEnabled.
```

And error disappears after cleaning the project (in Eclipse).

```
Project -> Clean..
```

Is there a fix without having to clean the project everytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ActionBar` class was added in API level 11, but not the method your are using. If you look at [the doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setHomeButtonEnabled%28boolean%29) you'll see that `setHomeButtonEnabled(boolean)` was added in **API level 14**.

Comment: I am using android studio with minSDK = 16 API, why do i get error at  getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

Comment: @PankajNimgade You have to set targetSDK to API 16 or higher too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, add action bar sherlock as a library. it allows you to work with API 8 and above.
https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock

Also while using actionbarsherlock, the code should be :

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Hi @King Omar, I want to know why the code mentioned in my question is giving the error. I've checked and found that ActionBar can be used in Android API level 11. (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html). Is AndroidBarSherlock library the only option?

Comment: sometimes eclipse irritates you. Sherlock is for backward compatibility( < API 11) when you want to support actionbar in older versions.

Comment: Hi @Ketan, I don't want to try Sherlock library.

Comment: AFAIK..You have two options (sherlock or appcompat library) to support in lower versions.